# Remove apostrophe from a string using php

Tags: php

Is there a anyway to remove apostrophe from a string in php?
example:- If string is Mc'win then it should be shown as Mcwin

```
$Str = "Mc'win";
/*
    some code to remove the apostrophe
*/

echo $Str; // should display Mcwin
```

Comment: @Ghost I've used str_replace.. but didn't know how to replace a character with nothing... BTW thanx :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use str_replace.

```
$Str = str_replace('\'', '', $Str);
```

or

```
$Str = str_replace("'", '', $Str);
```

This will replace all apostrophes with nothing (the 2nd argument) from `$Str`.  The first example escapes the apostrophe so str_replace will recognize it as the character to replace and not part of the enclosure.

Answer (score 7):

If your variable has been sanitized, you may be frustrated to find you can't remove the apostrophe using  $string = str_replace("'","",$string);

```
$string = "A'bcde";
$string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo $string." = string after sanitizing (looks the same as origin)<br>";
$string = str_replace("'","",$string);
echo $string." ... that's odd, still has the apostrophe!<br>";
```

This is because sanitizing converts the apostrophe to `&#39;` , but you may not notice this, because if you echo the string it looks the same as the origin string.

You need to modify your replace search characters to `&#39;` 
which works after sanitizing.

```
$string = str_replace("&#39;","",$string);
```

Comment: Your response helped with my frustration. I did however need to amend your replace to;

$string = str_replace("&#039;","",$string);

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i got single quote issue when i wanted to store it to database (in my case MySQL). So, i remove the single quotes using this method

```
str_replace("'", "", trim($_GET["message"]))
```

But, the problems comes. Some data required us to have single quotes. So, instead of removing the quotes I try to save the single quotes (escaping single quotes) so it can be used in the future (in my case at Android)

My Idea is to replace from `'` to `''`.
So here is the final

```
$content = str_replace("'", "''", trim($_GET["message"])); // double quotes for escape single quotes
```

This answer is for someone that persist problem like me. I got better solution. Cheers!

Comment: In modern programming, you should be manually escaping quotes, but using prepared statements when interacting with your database.